# get name of day from array of dates

Tags: php

Im filtering holidays out of a given array of dates like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

$timestamp = strtotime('monday this week');
$holidays = array('Sonntag 17.04.','Dienstag 19.04.','Mittwoch 20.04.');

$days = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) :
 $days[] = strftime('%A %d.%m.', $timestamp);
 $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
endfor;

foreach($days AS $day) :
if (in_array($day, $holidays)) :
echo $day . ' is a holiday and ' . (strftime('%A', strtotime($day))) . '<br />';
else :
echo $day . '<br />';
endif;
endforeach;
```

now I would also like to get the name of the day like this:

"Tuesday 19.04. is a holiday and a Tuesday"

How can I achive this?

Comment: Could the last **Tuesday** be achieved by just getting the first word from the `day` variable? If so, it is just a `substr($day, strpos($day, ' ')-1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
$timestamp = strtotime('monday this week');
$holidays = array('Sonntag 17.04.','Dienstag 19.04.','Mittwoch 20.04.');
$enHolidays = array_map('daysToEn',$holidays);

$days = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) :
 $days[] = strftime('%A %d.%m.', $timestamp);
 $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
endfor;

foreach($days AS $day) :
if (in_array($day, $enHolidays)) :
echo daysToDe($day) . ' is a holiday and ' . daysToDe(strftime('%A', strtotime($day))) . '<br />';
else :
echo $day . '<br />';
endif;
endforeach;


function daysToEn($dayName) {
    $engDays = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday');
    $duDays = array('Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag','Sonntag');
    return str_replace($duDays,$engDays,$dayName);
}

function daysToDe($dayName) {
    $engDays = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday');
    $duDays = array('Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag','Sonntag');
    return str_replace($engDays,$duDays,$dayName);
}
```

Comment: thanks but this doesnt work. I always get the same value (thursday) for each day.

Comment: @hes
It's working well.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5757a0558251b0f831d81978337dfe9990a1e909

Comment: hmm, you´re right. Maybe not in my case because Im using setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF8', 'de_DE')?

Comment: @hes which version of PHP do you use?
Do you get any error or warning?

Comment: @hes Also, you missed some dots at the end of $holidays elements. (Line #2).
I fixed them as well. Look at this: https://www.diffnow.com/?report=2uq7o

Comment: PHP 5.3.6-8 - no warnings or errors. Just always the same day :(

Comment: Without the setlocale it works. But I need it for the german dates. Any ideas?

Comment: @hes Try this at the start of file: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

Comment: @hes Done. Edited in answer.